# Trigger an instance replacement on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an application running on Elastic Beanstalk, and I wish to automatically trigger instance replacements twice weekly (Mondays and Fridays).

What is the best way to achieve this? Can it be done with ebextensions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it. Preferably from a lambda function which is triggered on a schedule using CloudWatch event rules. Basically your lambda function would have to use AWS SDK to **re-deploy existing application** version on EB. There is number of [deployment strategies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.deploy-existing-version.html), but one which garanteses replacement of instances is *Immutable*. In AWS CLI this is how you would do it:

```
aws elasticbeanstalk  update-environment  --environment-name Fff-env --version-label  "Sample Application"   --option-settings Namespace=aws:elasticbeanstalk:command,OptionName=DeploymentPolicy,Value=Immutable
```

You have to adapt the above CLI to AWS SDK of your chosen programming language (Python, Go, Java, ...)